# Signals-slots system: defining signal (magic macro needed)

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I need to have signals/slots analog (with no boost) of Qt's signals/slots system. The problem is that if I want to call signal's slots, I need to generate some code. Look at this example:

```
struct Test
{
    void on_mouse_click_event(int x, int y) // #1
    {
        using Function = void (Test::*)(int x, int y); // #2
        auto event_id_receivers_pair = event_id_to_receivers_.find(typeid(Function).hash_code());
        if(event_id_receivers_pair != event_id_to_receivers_.end())
        {
            FunctionArgs<Function> args(x, y); // #3
            for(auto& p_receiver : event_id_receivers_pair->second)
                p_receiver->call(&args);
        }
        on_mouse_click(x, y);
    }

    virtual void on_mouse_click(int x, int y)
    {
        std::cout << "On click: " << x << ", " << y
            << " - " << this << "\n";
    }

    std::unordered_map<
        std::size_t/*Function (event) ID*/,
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ICallee>>/*Array of receivers*/>
        event_id_to_receivers_;
 };

struct Foo
{
    void test_click(int x, int y)
    {
        std::cout << "On test click: " << x << ", " << y
            << " - " << this << "\n";
    }
};

template<typename Sender, typename Receiver, typename Signal, typename Slot>
void connect(Sender* sender, Signal signal,
    Receiver* receiver, Slot slot)
{
    auto callee = create_callee<Receiver, Slot>(receiver, slot);
    sender->event_id_to_receivers_[
        typeid(Signal).hash_code()].
            push_back(std::move(callee));
}

int main()
{
    Test test;
    Foo foo;
    Foo foo1;

    connect(&test, &Test::on_mouse_click_event,
        &foo, &Foo::test_click);

    connect(&test, &Test::on_mouse_click_event,
        &foo1, &Foo::test_click);

    test.on_mouse_click_event(10, 20);
}
```

class `Test` has an event `on_mouse_click()`. In main, I have 2 connections to this event and last line is event's emit. As a result, I want to see something like this:

```
On click: 10, 20 - 009CFC63
On click: 10, 20 - 009CFC57
On test click: 10, 20 - 009CFC6C
```

The question: is there a way for me to have some macro to write the code like this:

```
class Test
{
    SIGNAL(on_mouse_click)(int x, int y);
};
```

I need to have:

1. Type of pointer to member function : `void (Test::*)(int x, int y); // #2`
2. Names of function parameters to pass them around: `args(x, y); // #3`

Is this possible ? Are there any workarounds ?

Thanks

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. You probably don't want a macro, but a template function that activates a signal. So inside of `on_mouse_click` you'd simply call `activate(&Test::on_mouse_click, x, y)`. That function can then look up any functor(s) attached to the slot, and invoke them. You'd pass the method pointer so that you can use your member pointers when connecting things. The packaging of function arguments is unnecessary unless you want to have queued/deferred slot calls.

Comment: Just use some easier observer pattern implementation